# how to solve error " Configuration cannot be resolved to a type" in eclipse

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPRem.png)

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

}

Comment: refer image for more clarification

Comment: Configuration is not a valid annotation, and so Eclipse does not recognise it. Is there any more context for this question?

Comment: Missing spring dependency. Make sure that right libraries should be available on the classpath.